# Clustering matrix columns

Tags: python, matrix, data-science, k-means, knn

I'm trying to build clusters into a matrix. The matrix represent the presence of products in an image. I have a first row with products references and a first column with videos references. My matrix contains binary values for exemple.

| 3011360014993 | 4000400155023 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |

There can be up to 40 columns for 400 rows. My aim is to find the most similar columns and gather them (up to 5 columns)

I'm not into data science and heard about K-Means with Hamming Distance but also K-Medoids that would be more appropriate for binary values. I also heard of K-NN but I have no idea about what would be the better options and how to set it up.

I struggled with K-Means.

I also gave K-Medoids a shot with  here's my python script but I don't think that I'm doing well.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
from sklearn_extra.cluster import KMedoids
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler


df = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\labelisation\\Documents\\matrix2.xlsx")

df = df.fillna(0).astype(int)

print(df.head)

kmedoids = KMedoids(n_clusters=round(len(df.columns)/28), random_state=0).fit(df)

labels = kmedoids.labels_
print("this is labels")
print(labels)
print("this is clusters centers")
print(kmedoids.cluster_centers_)
```